# Right approximation in certain subcategories

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra and $C$ a subcategory of mod-$A$ that contains all projective modules and is closed under finite direct sums (but not necessarily under direct summands).
Let $T:=add(C)$.

For an $A$-module $M$, let $f: X \rightarrow M$ be a right $C$-approximation with $X$ in $C$. Then it sounds plausible that a minimal right $T$-approximation $g: Y \rightarrow M$ has the property that $Y$ is a direct summand of $X$, since this is characterised by $Hom(Z,g)$ being epi for all $Z \in add(C)$ (and C and add(C) are the same up to multiplicity of summands).

But since I get a strange consequence for this in a special case (and I never really worked with subcategory that are not closed under direct summands), I wanted to ask about this here.

> Question: Is there a reference for this? (is it even correct?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is true. By Proposition 5.1.2 of *Relative Homological Algebra* by Enochs and Jenda, a minimal right $T$-approximation will be a direct summand of any right $T$-approximation.

Therefore it suffices to show that $f:X\to M$ is also a right $T$-approximation. Let $h:\tilde{Y}\to M$ be any morphism with $\tilde{Y}\in T$. Then there is a $Z\in T$ such that $\tilde{Y}\oplus Z\in C$ and nonzero map $h\circ\pi :\tilde{Y}\oplus Z\to M$. Since $f:X\to M$ is a right $C$-approximation, there is an $\alpha:\tilde{Y}\oplus Z\to X$ such that $f\circ\alpha = h\circ\pi$. This clearly restricts to a non-zero map $\alpha\vert:\tilde{Y}\to X$ such that $g = f\circ\alpha\vert$. In other words, $f:X\to M$ is a right $T$-approximation.

Comment: Thanks, I wait some time so maybe has a concrete reference and then I accept this as an answer. It seems my proof showing that $Hom(Z,g)$ is epi needs more or less exactly your argument.